# How to control the volume output of each earphone in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, audio, swift4

I'm trying to control the relative volumes of each earphone (the Left and the Right) in Swift 4. Is there a way to do this? I have tried looking it up, but it seems that it is only possible to do this from `Settings` in the `Accessibility` category.